# Rewriting Links with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, query-string

I have a few hyperlinks like this on my page

```
<a href="http://www.otherdomain.com?r=1234" class="rewrite">Link</a>
```

When there is a query string in the address, example: `mydomain.com?r=abcd` the hyperlink should change to `<a href="http://www.otherdomain.com?r=abcd" class="rewrite">Link</a>`

I want the same thing to happen to "rh" query argument also. ie, when someone goes to `mydomain.com?rh=abcd`

This `<a href="http://www.otherdomain.com?r=1234" class="rewrite">Link</a>`

should change to `<a href="http://www.otherdomain.com?rh=abcd" class="rewrite">Link</a>`

Basically the script should say: if the queries "r" and "rh" is not null, the links with the class=rewrite must be changed. Everything after the "?" must be removed & the query string in the address should be added to the hyperlinks.

Comment: If you want to mark several link as target for rewrite you should use a class and not multiple ids. I'm refering here to `id="rewrite"`. I'll take a look at it, but I guess someone aelse will be faster. -- Still you should post you script, since SO is for helping not for complete programming requests.

Comment: I got it eventually but the question isn't entirely clear. And your second example is not consistent with your conclusion: shouldn't the original link be `...?rh=1234` in that example?

Comment: This also constitutes a "make the codez for me plz"

Comment: No. the original link will always have ...?r=1234.

Comment: @ShyamSundar: So, your question is really: "if the current page URL has an argument 'r' or 'rh' in the querystring, for each link in my webpage with class 'rewrite', I want the link href's querystring to be replaced by the current page URL's querystring. Please make it for me."

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal ok, i found [this](http://www.artisnavi.com/ttaching-custom-ids-to-links-based-on-the-query-string/?ref=single). but, i'm not sure if it helps achieve what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal yes that is correct. i've never coded before and i'm trying to find someone who can.

Comment: @ShyamSundar: This is still not a valid Stack Overflow question. I think you're looking for a chatroom where people help you write your code from scratch.

Comment: Not a valid question for this community. Take it to Yahoo answers or a similar site.

Answer (score 0):

change the domain:

```
var newurl = 'http://testdomain.com';

$('a').each(function(I,EL){
  var url = $(EL).attr('href');

  if(url.indexOf('?')>= 0){
     url = url.split('?');
     url = newurl + url[1];
     $(EL).attr('href', url);
  }

}
```